# join or outer() on a vector applied to rep()

Tags: r

I thought this was going to be very easy, but it turned out to be very hard. It's a simple problem: I have a vector of names:

```
[1] David    David    David    Nathan   Holly    Holly    Holly    Holly   
[9] Holly    Sue      Sue      Sue      Sue      Sue      Rene     Michelle
[17] Michelle Michelle Jennie   Jennie   Jennie   Jennie
```

I want to make a vector of indices so each name gets the same index:

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7
```

I got the number of each name using

```
bar <- ddply(df, .(Rater.Name), summarize, rater.n=sum(!is.na(Rater.Name)))
```

I tried

```
lapply(bar$Rater.Name, rep(1:7, bar$rater.n))
```

and all kinds of other things such as outer(), by(), etc. None worked. I ended up using a clumsy for loop, but it seems there should be a much more "R-like" way to do it. Can anyone suggest a way?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `factor`:

```
as.numeric(factor(x))

# [1] 1 1 1 5 2 2 2 2 2 7 7 7 7 7 6 4 4 4 3 3 3 3
```

This one orders by default in alphabetical order. If you don't desire that (ex: `2` instead of `5` for `Nathan`...) then do:

```
as.numeric(factor(x, levels=x[!duplicated(x)]))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have anything particularly negative to say about using `factor`, but you might learn an additional trick and an exceedingly useful function by looking at `match`:

```
> dat <- scan(what="")
1:  David    David    David    Nathan   Holly    Holly    Holly    Holly   
9:  Holly    Sue      Sue      Sue      Sue      Sue      Rene     Michelle
17:  Michelle Michelle Jennie   Jennie   Jennie   Jennie  
23: 
Read 22 items
> match(dat, unique(dat))
 [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick with converting it to a factor first:

```
> x <- c('David', 'David', 'Lena', 'David')
> as.factor(x)
[1] David David Lena  David
Levels: David Lena
> y <- as.factor(x)
> y
[1] David David Lena  David
Levels: David Lena
> as.numeric(y)
[1] 1 1 2 1
```